# How to change dot circle color of RadioButtonList in asp.net?

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms, css-selectors

I tried to change dot circle color of RadioButtonList:

```
<style>
.radioboxlist radioboxlistStyle
{
font-size:x-large;
padding-right: 20px;
}
.radioboxlist label {

}
.radioboxlist label:hover
{
color: darkgreen;
background: white;

}
input:checked + label {
color: darkgreen;
font-size:large;

background: white;
border-color:green;
}
 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
            background-color: yellow;
            color:yellow;
        }
    </style>
```

mark

```
 `<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" BackColor="#E1EFD0" BorderColor="#E1EFD0" BorderStyle="Outset" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="5" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" Height="31px" Width="211px" CssClass="radioboxlist">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">A</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
               
            </asp:RadioButtonList>`
```

I tried it with using "input[type="radio"]:checked" but it does not change color of dot circles of RadioButtonList

In older version they use accent-color but I do not have that option in my CSS...

Answer (score 0):

You in general have to override the button.

but, this works:

```
    <style>
        .rRed input[type='radio']:after {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            top: -2px;
            left: -1px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: red;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            visibility: visible;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }

        .rRed input[type='radio']:checked:after {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            top: -2px;
            left: -1px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: blue;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            visibility: visible;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
    </style>
```

So, above has the 2 colors (for selected, and not selected).

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"                
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="rRed" >
    <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And thus we get/see this:

[image]

## Edit: Hover color setting

To set hover color, try this:

```
    <style>
        .rRed input[type='radio']::after {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            top: -2px;
            left: -1px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: red;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            visibility: visible;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }

        .rRed input[type='radio']:checked::after {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            top: -2px;
            left: -1px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: blue;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            visibility: visible;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
        .rRed input[type='radio']:hover::after  {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            top: -2px;
            left: -1px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: skyblue;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            visibility: visible;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
    </style>


<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"                
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="rRed"  >
    <asp:ListItem >A</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

We get this:

[image]

Comment: It works fine. I also tried to hover over uncheked items with this  input[type='radio']:hover:after   which works but when tried to hover over checked itmes it doesnt work I tried this: checked:hover or checked:hover:after none of the works...

Comment: See my 2nd edit - I show a working hover color.